# Correct coefficients of the fourth power of a sum

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Consider the following summation raised to the power $4$: 
$$S^4 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\right)^4$$.

Clearly this can be expanded as
$$
S^4 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^4 + \sum_{i \ne j} a x_i x_j (x_i x_j  + b (x_i^2 + x_j^2)) + \sum_{i \ne j \ne k} c (x_i x_j x_k (x_i + x_j + x_k)) + \sum_{i\ne j\ne k\ne l} x_i x_j x_k x_l$$
(all summations are over the range of $\{1,2,...,n\}$)

I was wondering what are the correct coefficients $a$, $b$, and $c$ in the above expansion?

Comment: @Bernard I think all sums are degree 4 terms.  Am I mistaking?

Comment: :Oops! Sorry! I was looking at two questions more or less simultaneously, and messed up myself.  I'll replace my comment.

Comment: There is indeed a multinomial formula, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem). There are also Newton's relations between sums of powers and elementary symmetric functions.